# Why can't I purchase the full version of Magic 2014 on Steam?

Tags: steam, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2014

I downloaded the demo version of Magic 2014 on Steam. Now I wanted to look what the full version would cost but when I click on *Purchase Full Game* this screen appears:
[image: steam screen]

So, where can I purchase the full version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not exactly looking at page to purchase the full version, but rather page for buying **the game's DLC** (which it doesn't have any), you are in a wrong page if you want to buy the game.

Here is the link to purchase **the game itself**: http://store.steampowered.com/app/213850/

Comment: +1 for helping to explain why his current link wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

You can purchase the full version on Magic 2014 Steam Store page through [this link](http://store.steampowered.com/app/213850).